# Semi-continuity of the dimension of the null space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Suppose $T_n : X \rightarrow X$ is a sequence of Fredholm operators on a Banach space such that $T_k \rightarrow T$ strongly (in the induced operator norm). If $N_k$ and $N$ denote the dimensions of the respective null spaces. Is it true that $$\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty}N_k \leq N ?$$

What if the convergence is only in the weak topology, i.e $T_k(x) \rightarrow T(x)$ for all $x\in X$? The result is of course true for finite dimensional matrices, so I am mainly interested in the infinite dimensional case. I have included the Fredholm condition just to ensure that $N_k$ are finite, but I am not sure if the full strength is needed. Or maybe the above statement also needs $T_k$ to be compact operators? Any thoughts are welcome. And even better if you have some proofs, counter examples or references.

Comment: First note that $T_k$ compact and Fredholm implies $X$ finite dimensional. Answer to the question as stated is negative. Take $X=\ell_p$ and let $T_k$ be an operator of multiplication by a sequence $(a^k_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. If we take $a^k_n=0$ when $2^k<n<2^{k+1}$ and $1/n$ otherwise the $N_k=2^k$ and $T_k$ converges in norm to $T$ being a multiplication by $1/n$ which has $N=0$. I think if you assume that $T$ is Fredholm then the answer is yes for norm convergence. For weak it is still no--take as above but $a^k_n=0$ when $2^k<n<2^{k+1}$ and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: $T_n$ as defined above is not Fredholm, modify as follows :  $a^k_n=0 $ when $2^k<n<2^{k+1}$,  $1/n$ for $n\leq 2^k$ and $2^{-k}$ when $n\geq 2^{k+1}$.